# ddrescue on SD-card: Why is the output differing but no errors given?

Tags: sd-card, ddrescue

I'm doing a backup operation on a SD-card. This card has been used for almost 8 y with regular write operation. Chances are that it is damaged somehow.
That's why I choose ddrescue to get the content.

```
# sudo ddrescue /dev/mmcblk0 /tmp/backup.img
```

ddrescue runs with no perceivable slowdowns (4 GiB) and gives no errors. However I was curious and ran

```
# sudo cmp /dev/mmcblk0 /tmp/backup.img
```

which ends up in a byte differing amid the file. I thought I could do another image and compare them. However the images keep differing from the card and from each other. How comes that I cannot see any errors, warnings or strange behaviour during the rescue operation? dmesg doesn't show any errors either.

What should I assume? That a backup isn't possible?
What should I do to get an image with most similarities to the original?

**Update**

I made eight backups, all differ. There is an extremely large number of differences. If I do a `cmp -l <a> <b> | wc -l` between any two of the eight backups I made, the number is always greater than 100000. So showing the output doesn't make much sense. The differences start from varying points in the file but there seem to be some statistic correlations. I'm not done analyzing that yet.

Comment: Did you unmount all filesystems of the card prior to `ddrescue`?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski I didn't mount the device before trying to rescue it. I have turned off automount. I did this process with a similar card some days before. Hadn't encountered that then. However, maybe I have missed something related. I will repeat that process to rule that problem out. Thanks!

Comment: `a byte differing` are you saying that there is one single byte that is wrong? did you use `-l` to identify the byte and the difference?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I'll update my question accordingly. There is more than one differing byte.

Comment: No problems, Scorpie (literally watching Farscape now) :p if it's not too many, can you show the output of `cmp -l`